# Exporting MEMO Fields From DBISAM

Tags: excel, dbisam

I have several `DBISAM Database` tables, I can read them and edit them. But when I export the Data to an `excel` spreadsheet it doesn't export the **MEMO** fields located in the table. Does anyone know of a way to export the **MEMO** fields so i do not have to open them individually and copy and paste them to an Excel spreadsheet?

I have googled my problem and have found no solution. There was one solution, to purchase an export tool from a company overseas but the website seemed sketchy to me and I am trying to find a free way to do this.

Elevated software says they cant export **MEMO** fields because they don't read right when importing to other programs.

I'm hoping someone has found another way...I have Tens of thousands records that I need to export so this would save me a lot of time if there were a way.

Answer (score 0):

After talking with "elevate software" they indicated that this column  was incorrectly  setup as a memo to store images should have been setup as a BLOB type instead to properly work with images and scans.  I copied the needed columns into a new temp table and altered the memo type to BLOB in the new table so as not to disrupt the old table.  I then exported this table to mssql via the mssql import export wizard and the images came across correctly.  I used an ssis job to then extract those to individual files and can view and work with the images as needed. It may be an extra step to goto mssql and then excel, but might work.